# Date Range Interpolation in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an Event class with a start and end date and specific days of the week the event can occur:

```
public class Event
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek[] DayOfWeekList { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I can have events that occur once:

```
Event 1: StartDate = 9/15/2013, EndDate = 9/15/2013, DOW = Sunday
```

I can have events that are multi-day:

```
Event 2: StartDate = 9/15/2013, EndDate = 9/16/2013, DOW = Sunday, Monday
```

I can have events that occur over a date range but only specific, possibly non-contiguous days of the week, e.g., during the month of September but only Tuesday and Thursday:

```
Event 3: StartDate = 9/1/2013, EndDate = 9/30/2013, DOW = Tuesday, Thursday
```

Given a date range of 9/1 - 9/16 I'd like to display the events as one event day record in the grid as follows:

```
Event 3: 9/3/2013 Tuesday
Event 3: 9/5/2013 Thursday
Event 3: 9/10/2013 Tuesday
Event 3: 9/12/2013 Thursday
Event 1: 9/15/2013 Sunday
Event 2: 9/15/2013 Sunday
Event 2: 9/16/2013 Monday
```

I'll only store one Event record in the db to represent the event days instead of one record for each day. So for the date range above I'll retrieve the 3 Event records from the db and will need to generate a sequence of Event records for this date range based on the schedule using the event's days of week.

I'll use Linq to SQL to retrieve the 3 Event records but then need to expand each event's schedule to create new Event records, one for each day. This seems less than efficient especially if the website becomes widely used.

Is there some way this can be accomplished using Linq?

The alternative is to have distinct child records for each day the event occurs in the db but this will be a pain to maintain if someone changes the schedule from every Monday to every Tuesday for exaple. Also we can have events without a defined end date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a brute force solution, but something like this should work:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 16);
var totalDays = (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1;
var results = 
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
    let d = startDate.AddDays(i)
    from e in eventList 
    where e.StartDate <= d && 
          e.EndDate >= d &&
          e.DayOfWeekList.Contains(d.DayOfWeek)
    select new { Event = e, Date = d };
```

This generates the correct results when I tested it in memory. Unfortunately, this will probably not translate well to pure Linq-to-SQL code. I think your best bet is to materialized a subset of events first and then use a modified query to generate the final result set in memory:

```
var eventList = 
    (from e in db.Events 
     where e.StartDate <= endDate && 
           e.EndDate >= startDate
     select e)
    .AsEnumerable();
var results = 
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
    let d = startDate.AddDays(i)
    from e in eventList 
    where e.StartDate <= d && 
          e.EndDate >= d &&
          e.DayOfWeekList.Contains(d.DayOfWeek) 
    select new { Event = e, Date = d };
```

Comment: This works perfectly when I add this to your results query:

    `&& d >= e.StartDate && d <= e.EndDate`

Comment: @TxDeveloper Ahh, yes that makes sense. You need to do additional filtering on the precise range of the event. I've updated my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Your second code block, the 2nd part of the Where statement should be `e.StartDate <= endDate && e.EndDate >= startDate`, you have used `endDate` for both so it wont work. Once that is fixed the first statement in your Where become redundant.

Comment: Also your calculation of `totalDays` is off, you need to add 1, since you want it inclusive of the start and end day, not the number of days elapsed (consider start = Jan 1, end = Jan 2, your totalDays would be 1 and thus ignore the final day).

Answer (score 1):

If you most often read events, and don't mind a small extra cost saving them, you could choose to materialize your events based on the rules into a new table. This table could be cleaned out and regenerated if you want based on the rules, or selectively repopulated as needed.

Event 1 when saved would create a single entry, with EventID:1

Event 2 when saved would create entries for the date range that match the DOW property, with EventID:2

Event 3 would do the same but with its date range/DOW, with EventID:3

You could use some fancy LINQ to work out what rows to add if you want, but the end result is you want physical instance rows for really easy querying.

When updating an event you could simply delete all rows for that EventID and re-create them based on the changes.

Given the above, your read operation could be as simple as:

```
EventInstances.Where(i => i.Date >= startDate && i.Date <= endDate);
```

If instead you want slow/complex reads and fast writes you would need to generate this in-memory map each time you read.

**UPDATE: some code to show what I mean**

The logic to populate the table is the exact same logic you could use to create an in-memory table:

```
// slightly updated Event class
public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek[] DayOfWeekList { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 16);
var totalDays = (int)endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays + 1;

// sample data, including a 4th event starting a while ago with no end date
var events = new List<Event> {
    new Event { ID = 1, Title = "Event 1", StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 15), EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 15), DayOfWeekList = new[] { DayOfWeek.Sunday } },
    new Event { ID = 2, Title = "Event 2", StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 15), EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 16), DayOfWeekList = new[] { DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday } },
    new Event { ID = 3, Title = "Event 3", StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 30), DayOfWeekList = new[] { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday } },
    new Event { ID = 4, Title = "Event 4", StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), EndDate = null, DayOfWeekList = new[] { DayOfWeek.Wednesday } },
};

var eventsInRange = events
    .Where(e => e.StartDate <= endDate)
    .Where(e => (e.EndDate == null || e.EndDate.Value >= startDate ))
    // if you are getting from the database, force this data to be 
    // retrieved since the following section would not work with the DB
    .AsEnumerable();

var daysInRange = Enumerable
    .Range(0, totalDays)
    .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));

var eventInstances = daysInRange
    .SelectMany(d => eventsInRange
        .Where(e => e.EndDate == null || d <= e.EndDate.Value)
        .Where(e => d >= e.StartDate)
        .Where(e => e.DayOfWeekList.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
        .Select(e => new { Date = d, Day = d.DayOfWeek, Event = e }));
```

If you wanted to populate a table with this data for easier querying, just set the start date and end date based on what is reasonable (e.g. start 1 year ago, end 2 years time).

If you wanted to re-populate just for one event after an update, just remove all records for that event ID and limit the `eventsInRange` to just be the event updated.

Comment: This will be my alternative method and the most straightforward when displaying the events but will be a pain to maintain, especially for the events that no defined end date. Thanks.

Comment: For those with no defined end date, you have to set an acceptable level for forward data to create. I believe this is how many calendar programs work (e.g. Outlook). You could then even handle one-off exceptions (e.g. someone wants to cancel a single instance for some reason) by including that logic in the populate code.